# How to deal with potentially non-existing input files (*.txt)

Tags: sas

**Context:**

I am reading in (using `DATA STEP infile`) a lot of of folders (around 80) basically containing three categories of `*.txt` files (4 ASCII files), process them and then sometimes merge (actually coalesce using `DATA STEP set`) those data sets into two for each folder and then over all folders.
Sometimes it happens, that one or two categories are missing and `SAS` will throw an `ERROR message ("ERROR: Physical file does not exist")` but still proceed and it seems everything is still working. `SAS` seems to generate an empty data sets (no obs) and work with those.

**Question:**
Anyway, I want to get rid of those `ERRORS` and check with an `%IF` statement whether the file exists - which works - and otherwise skip the data step. But I get a new source of `ERRORS` when I try to merge those non-existing data sets, also I am sorting those data sets with respect to a variable, which ofc also does not exist - `ERROR`. I was thinking of checking whether the data set is empty and depending on this merge etc. but I am not sure if this is the best idea. Any recommendations? Also, it already takes a lot of time for `SAS` to process all the data. From a time-consuming POV is this a good idea (check for fileexist etc.)?

**My solution:**

- catch those non-existing files with an `%IF` statement and `%fileexist`
- generate a data set (automatically has 1 observation) which contains only the variable I am sorting by
- remove the observation
- it follows the `DATA STEP set`
- delete the empty data sets

It depends a bit on how much data the ASCII files contain but this whole process takes already 1.5 minutes and I will have to add some more data. Is the `DATA STEP infile` that slow?

Comment: Show the code that is generating the errors.  What is 'a lot' ? 100 ? 1,000 ? 10,000 ? Say there were 1,000 folders -- How are you creating each of the 1K data sets from the 3K(+?) files ?  Are you reading data files with `Proc IMPORT` or `DATA` step with `INFILE`.  How are you merging the three categories into a single data set for each folder ? How are you building up that final BIG data set ?  Three data steps *could* read each category of file from all the folders and then three final sorts for those and one merge into FINAL.

Comment: @Richard Good points, I'll add a clarifying edit asap.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing that is causing you to have "missing" files. If you are processing a folder how is one of the files in the folder missing?  Wouldn't it just not make it into the list of files to process?

Comment: Where is the list of 80 folders coming from? Is it in a dataset? Are they all in the same directory tree?  How are you classifying the text files? Is it based on their name? Some other attribute of the file?

Comment: @Tom Those files really don't exist and that's completely within expectation. Here is why: Each year a couple of institutes (volatile,average 80) are sending collected data to us,each institute one folder.All of them are collecting data of three categories but not every year every institute all 3, this changes over the year and is not known beforehand. Now I need to process the data and to facilitate this I wrote a `macro`. Since I don't want to check all folders what kind of category it contains the `macro` sometimes encounters those 'missing' files and now I wonder how to deal with it bests.

Comment: @Tom (...for completeness) the `macro` parameter is then the folder, within the `macro` I call via `data step infile` the `*.txt` files which may or may not exist. Those file names are within the categories all the same by convention.

Comment: Show what actual SAS code your macro is currently generating. At least enough to show what is causing the trouble.  Are you saying you are doing something like `infile '*.txt' ...` and the infile statement doesn't find anything?

Comment: @Tom exactly, `data step infile` fails to find the physical file (since it doesn't exist). So I catch this with `%IF %fileexist()` for every `*.txt`. I'll add some example code and check your answer, thx so far!

Answer (score 0):

You can use %sysfunc(fileexist()) macro function.
Try the following code. When passing the FILE argument, make sure it contains full path.

```
%macro check(file);
  %if %sysfunc(fileexist(&file)) %then %do;
    %put File &file exists.;

    %* YOUR CODE HERE *;

  %end;
  %else
    %put The external file &file does not exist.;
%mend;
```

e.g.

`%check(/user/lukas/util/test.csv);`

Comment: Thx, that's pretty much what I was doing to catch the `"ERROR: Physical file does not exist"`. I also edited my question a bit to provide some more info. The problem basically is that the execution is sort of slow and I have to basically create (empty) files which I need to delete again which seems more like a workaround than a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you will want to first get the list of files and then process them. For example you could use operating system commands to get the list of files.  (or search for code that use SAS's `dread()` function to get a list).

```
data files ;
   infile "ls &path/*.txt" pipe truncover ;
   input filename $256.;
run;
```

Then you can use the list of files to drive your later steps. So perhaps by using the FILEVAR= option on the INFILE statement.

```
 data want;
    set files ;
    fname=filename;
    infile txt filevar=fname end=eof dsd truncover ;
    do while (not eof);
       input .... ;
       output;
    end;
 run;
```